# Android Retrofit 2 Работа с cookie

Tags: android, cookie, retrofit, retrofit2

Есть ли возможность в Retroft 2 на android автоматизировать процесс получения и отправки cookie файлов?

1) Если пришли cookie их нужно добавить в HttpClient который использует Retrofit2. Если не ошибаюсь, мне нужно этот самый клиент настроить и передать Retrofit2.

2) Как только пришли cookie их необходимо сохранить на android устройстве, что бы при следующем открытии приложения cookie загрузились и передались HttpClien`у

3) Автоматически прикреплять cookie при каждом запросе HtppClient`а если это необходимо. Указать какую то стратегию/указать это аннотацией например.

P.S. Сейчас я при каждом ответе на каждый вызов сам пишу о том, что бы cookie сохранялись в Preferences(Android). `pref.putCookie(res.headers().get("Set-Cookie"));`

И при каждом вызове беру из Preferences и вставляю вручную `Observable<Response<String>> ping(@Header("Cookie") String cookie, @Field("val") String testVal);`.

Мне кажется хуже придумать уже нельзя.

P.S. Что касается api + cookie - это к теме не относится (я понимаю, что это плохое решение), это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Правильно, хуже уже нельзя. Куки были придуманы для других целей и использовать их в API для мобильных приложений плохая идея в принципе.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Для идентификации пользователя необходимо использовать api token или uuid, который хранить в БД?

Comment: Хранить где и как, это вопрос безопасности. А куки тут причем? Куки придумали для браузеров и пусть они их и используют. У них есть специальное защищенное хранилище и механизмы безопасного доступа к нему.

Comment: Перепишите вопрос, описав суть проблемы, а не как вы уже ее решили решать и у вас не получается. Тогда и ответы по существу появятся.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja у меня все получается, я не спорю и прекрасно понимаю, что api + cookie это плохая практика. Но мне кажется далеко не каждый проект идеален и тянет за собой кучу плохих решений. Но вопрос не об этом. Сейчас мне не нравится как я пишу код, и я уверен, что должны быть способы не писать мне самому логику работы с cookie в каждом запросе. На счет API, я точно буду его переделывать, но уже не сейчас. Спасибо за ответы, помогли выявить еще одну проблему.

Comment: Единственное, что могу добавить, напишите свой `OkHttp Interceptor`, он будет эти ваши куки на лету читать/писать: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто. Создаете куки джар:

```
public class MyCookieJar implements CookieJar {

    private List<Cookie> cookies;

    @Override
    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        this.cookies =  cookies;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
        if (cookies != null)
            return cookies;
        return new ArrayList<Cookie>();
    } 
}
```

И ставите его клиенту:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(new MyCookieJar())
    .build();
```

Comment: Jar - это как то связанно с архивом? Что бы сохранять cookie после выхода/входа в приложение необходимо как я понял поменять List на SharedPreferences ну и немножко допилить логику, да?

Comment: хм. сохраняйте юзерские данные для входа, входите при входе, а куки не сохраняйте потому что они могут умирать. а вообще наверное можно и в префсами коллекцию заменить

Comment: Спасибо, все встало на свои места. Но в процессе я понял, что решение крайне не удачное, совмещать cookie и api. Но в любом случае эти знания еще пригодятся.